# Reverse Engineering Wifi Chip-set Firmware

Tags: disassembly, linux, firmware

I have Sparrow Wireless Adapter which from Qualcomm originally Wilocity that supports Wifi over 60 GHz (802.11ad or WiGiG). I have the firmware files of the wireless chipset (wil6210.fw and wil6210.brd). I would like to know the following:

1. Did anyone manage to reverse engineer the firmware and and get an insight regarding the implementation?
2. How would it be possible to know if the firmware is protected/encrypted or not?
3. What is the best tool to dissemble the firmware file and extract useful information out of it and allow to build new firmware?

Comment: Does anybody know which BB processor wilocity is using: Mips or Arm?

Comment: It seems to be an ARC from Synopsys. IDA's ARCompact disassembly of the Wilocity target memory indicated that.